# Telegram messenger on android uses camera hiddenly

Tags: security, camera, telegram

Everytime I open Telegram messenger and wait for a few seconds, then I check Stock AppOps in my android setting, I see that telegram has used camera same time,  While I never used camera.
my telegram version is official. Is this a security risk from telegram or this is a normal function only?

[image]

Comment: It may have just used the camera APIs to check that it had access, it doesn't mean it was actually *using* the camera.

Comment: You can try removing the permission from Telegram, and see if it asks you for camera permission and check again this app to see if it was used. I don't have a source for it, but @Mokubai suggestions sounds reasonable.

Comment: It is 2019 and I still face the issue. I prohibit the Telegram access to my camera, but after a while it becomes enabled again. Even though I am very sure that I did not give the permission. That should be certainly a security risk.

Comment: @hellouworld If you are really concerned about the camera access ask the company that develops Telegram. In any way if you have disabled the camera access for telegram what are you worry about.

Comment: @Robert, the access is granted without my permission after a while an Telegram starts using the camera in background again.

Comment: In my case it is Xiaomi Mi 9 SE, Android 9.

Comment: That's very unusual. If you disable the permission for camera use in settings within Android it should not be used.